Does a US citizen need a transit visa in Korea?
I'm a US citizen traveling from Charlotte (CLT) to Dallas (DFW) to Incheon Seoul (ICN); my destination is Bali (DPS).  I'll have to pick up my bags at ICN and recheck it on the new airline to DPS; my layover in ICN is less than 24 hours. Will I need a visa?
